# Proving Equivalence Relations On A Set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, equivalence-relations, binary

Let X be the set of all nonempty subsets of {1,2,3}. Then

X = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}}

Define a relation **R** on X as follows: for all S and T in X, S**R**T if, and only if, the least element of S equals the least element of T. Prove that R is an equivalence relation on X.

So my question is, what are S and T? Are they some sort of set or are they elements in X? How would I go about proving that R is an equivalence relation on X?

Comment: $S$ and $T$ are elements of $X$.

Comment: $S$ and $T$ are (non-empty) subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$. One proves the relation is an equivalence relation by as usual verifying that the three defining properties hold. For example, let us show (reflexivity) that $S\mathbf{R}S$ holds for any $S$. Is the least element of $S$ equal to the least element of $S$? Sure.

Comment: So essentially, S and T are one of the 7 sets within X?

Comment: Yes, $S$ and $T$ are (not necessarily distinct) sets within $X$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

1)Reflexive:

Clear since if we have the same set then least elements are equal. So, $SRS$.

2) Symmetric:

Suppose $SRT$. Then least element of $S$ equals least element of $T$. Hence, least element of $T$ equals least element of $S$. So, $TRS$.

3) Transitive:

Suppose $SRT$ and $TRU$. Then least element of $S$ equals least element of $T$ and least element of $T$ equals least element of $U$. Hence, least element of $S$ equals least element of $U$. So, $SRU$.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that for me! However, I have a couple of questions. Could you use some examples of the set that show that each 3 conditions hold?

Comment: @Mark: Can you please elaborate your question? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: For example, to prove that R is reflexive, you stated why it is so. Could you further illustrate your argument by providing an example where you use one of the sets from X to demonstrate that?

Comment: For example, take $S=\{2\}$ and $T=\{2,3\}$. So $S\mathbf{R}T$.

Comment: The relation is $\rm S\mathbf R T \iff \min(S) = \min(T)$.  **Reflexive** is the property that: $\mathrm S\mathbf R \mathrm S$ is true for all $\rm S$ in $X$.  *One example* is that $\{2,3\}$ is in $X$ and $\min\{2,3\}=\min\{2,3\}$.  However, one example is *not* sufficient for a proof.  To prove we argue that $(\min(\mathrm S)=\min(\mathrm S))$ will be clearly be true for *any* example.